# Emulating fixed positioning in scrollable div in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Ok this one is really messed up.  Just try to run the following in JSfiddle.  If you try it in any other browser it works correctly.  If you run it in IE6, it will not work.

How do I make this work with IE6?

Also, content NEED to have position:relative.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .content {
            position: relative;
        }
        .scrollable {
            position: relative;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: #333;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        .fixed {
            position: fixed;
            top: 180px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 20px;
            background: #fa2;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="scrollable">
        <div class="content">
            im scrollable<br><br>
            im scrollable<br><br>
            im scrollable<br><br>
            im scrollable<br><br>
            im scrollable<br><br>
            im scrollable<br><br>
        </div>    
        <div class="fixed">and I'm fixed</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I know this wasn't your question, but it's about time we forget IE 6. Maybe it doens't need to look that pretty on an old, obsolete and buggy browser. =)

Comment: Tell that to my client who are paying me money.

Comment: @DanielCastro, yep, me to had some work to do with IE6, since my customer has no budget to upgrade IE to about 5k of his workers :)

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` doesn't work on IE6. You could use javascript to make `.fixed` go to its "fixed" place on window scroll & resize, but it wouldn't look as nice (it would move before the js brings it back)

Try [checking this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682989/faking-fixed-position-in-ie6)